# How to show Number of Views (like This link/page has been viewed 68 times) in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view

How to show Number of Views (like : This link/page has been viewed 68 times) in rails?
I sthere any gem or plugin available for it ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are following the usual MVC pattern, then a View is a representation of the object model and the best way to track a view count would be to simply add a 'number of times viewed' counter to the table.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add a counter column to your Model, and increment it whenever the page is hit in the controller.  As simple as this is, there are some design issues:

- Page caching will affect your stats.  In this case, you can still use Ajax on your page to register the hit. (Not much different than how google analytics works.)
- Do your pages already have an obvious relationship to a Model?  If they are user profile pages for example, put the counter in the Profile model.